# Qt Creator GDB "Additional Startup Command" , "Additional Attach Command" what is the syntax?

Tags: qt, gdb, qt-creator

Having troubles settings solib-search-path in Options->Debugger->GDB-> "Additional Startup Command" , "Additional Attach Command" looks like if I do:
"set solib-search-path ~/workspace/myproject/lib" it just gets ignored, and solib-search-path set to something else by Qt Creator.

So my question is, what is the syntax in subject fields if it is just plain GDB command or something else?

Probably the second question is how to force the Qt Creator to use my solib-search-path not whatever it comes up with?

Using Qt Creator 3.5.1, Qt 5.5.0

Comment: It is a plain gdb command, and I think it doesn't get ignored, but Qt Creator sends its own command. To see what's going on, look at the *Window->Views->Debugger Log* while the debugger is active.